# Clicking on an onclick element using Selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, onclick

I am using selenium webdriver to scrape data from a website. After the initial login into the page, i landed up on a page which has 2 buttons which invoke a post method. I want to click on the second button under the class clearFix.

```
</head>
    <body id="top">
        <form name="CMN010010Form" method="POST" action="/tmtwb/CMN010010Action.do">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="container">
                                
                    <div id="header">
                    </div><!--/header-->                
                    
                    <ul class="clearFix">
                            <li class="japanese"><input type="image" src="images/sp_btn_japanese.gif" style="width:210;height:41;" onclick="submitPage(document.forms['CMN010010Form'], document.forms['CMN010010Form'].Login, './CMN010010Action.do'); return false;"/></li>
                            <li class="english"><input type="image" src="images/sp_btn_english.gif"  style="width:210;height:41;" onclick="submitPage(document.forms['CMN010010Form'], document.forms['CMN010010Form'].Login, './CMN020010Action.do'); return false;"/></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="menu">
```

I tried to run the below command in python after creating the driver object.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"submitPage(document.forms['CMN010010Form'], document.forms['CMN010010Form'].Login, './CMN020010Action.do'); return false;\"]").click().
```

However, it fails and giving me below exception. Can someone help please?

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@onclick="submitPage(document.forms['CMN010010Form'], document.forms['CMN010010Form'].Login, './CMN020010Action.do'); return false;"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)
```

Comment: is mandatory to do it in just one line?

Comment: You are trying to target a button element but there is none

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

If `li` element raises click event, use the below xpath:

```
"//ul[@class='clearFix']//li[@class='english']"
```

else, use xpath below to target `image` tag inside `li`

```
"//ul[@class='clearFix']//li[@class='english']//input"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to run this but it did not trigger any response. The below solution by QHarr works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to trigger the submit via the input onclick event

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.english input').click()
```